# syntax error in commands

Tags: javascript, php, shell, shell-exec

I have an iframe to send the commands from control panel when the user clicks the button. Using the code below, nothing happens with the button when the user clicks as there is a syntax error in the code.

```
$items['googledotcom'] = array
        (
            'description'=>'DNS resolution test',
            '1'=>1,
            '0'=>0,
            'fixCommand'=>'EXC service network restart; echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolv.conf; sleep 10; health check',
        );
```

The above code doesn't work, because of this line: **echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolv.conf;**

But the code will work when I remove the above line. But I need to add the above line as well.

Any suggestions for the syntax?

Thanks!

UPDATE

Format of command:
[image]

doCommand Javascript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

function doCommand(command)
{
    var r=confirm("Are you sure you want to \"" + command + "\"");
    if (!r)
    {
        return;
    }

    $.post('/device/commands-frame/', { id : '<?=$this->site->id;?>', act : command, command : command }, function(data)
    {
        alert('Command has been sent');
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: When the button clicks, nothing happens. otherwise I will get an alert

Comment: *"nothing happens"* isn't very helpful. Have you enabled error reporting? What is the result of attempting to issue that command?

Comment: I am using a javascript to send this command to the remote device. I have updated a picture to see how the commands send. When I click the send button, i should get a confirmation message. But this code doesn't give anything as output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$items['googledotcom'] = array
    (
        'description'=>'DNS resolution test',
        '1'=>1,
        '0'=>0,
        'fixCommand'=>"EXC service network restart; echo 'nameserver 8.8.8.8' >> /etc/resolv.conf; sleep 10; curo health check"
    );
    var_dump($items);
?>
```

This shows:

```
array(1) { ["googledotcom"]=> array(4) { ["description"]=> string(19) "DNS resolution test" [1]=> int(1) [0]=> int(0) ["fixCommand"]=> string(103) "EXC service network restart; echo 'nameserver 8.8.8.8' >> /etc/resolv.conf; sleep 10; curo health check" } }
```

Now i test the value with the following fiddle and it's working:
http://jsfiddle.net/EjXmp/

That fiddle contains the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#clickme").click(function(){
doCommand("EXC service network restart; echo 'nameserver 8.8.8.8' >> /etc/resolv.conf; sleep 10; curo health check");
});

function doCommand(command)
{
var r=confirm("Are you sure you want to \"" + command + "\"");
if (!r)
{
    return;
}

$.post('/device/commands-frame/', { id : '<?=$this->site->id;?>', act : command, command : command }, function(data)
{
    alert('Command has been sent');
});
}

});
```

Comment: Other than adding some debugging, what does this do differently?

Comment: Tested on my localhost, and working...no error...thanks for the -1 ;)

Comment: How about the OP's code. Does that *not work*?

Comment: Wathever you say, dude ;)

Comment: I'm not meaning to be dismissive. Your code does nothing different to the OP's other than switching the quotes around `nameserver 8.8.8.8` which in a shell context, makes no difference.

Comment: Maybe when the user hit the button, then an alert with the content of fixCommand is triggered; however, the way it is originally brokes the javascript code...just maybe ;)

Comment: I have tried the above code as well. But no difference :(

Comment: Show me the doCommand JS function

Comment: I apologise Robert. The OP left out details that shows switching the quotes *is* the right thing to do

Comment: Don't worry Phil...Rome wasn't built in a day ;)

Comment: I have updated the javascript function

Comment: @RobertRozas If you edit your answer, I can reverse the vote

Comment: We are here to help...feel free to ask ;)